How to achieve believable interior night light in Unity URP?
I have scene which shows inside of an house. I am trying to achieve night as shown in horror movies. But in order to light up the entire room I have to increase the intensity of light way too much. This creates a intense white spot near the light source.
If anyone has any solution for this or even an example interior night lighting(artificial light inside house) please share.
This is currently what I have:

I am trying to achieve this:

This is the reference image. Although it is a exterior environment it is the type of look I am trying to achieve with the interior.
https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4b/0e/8d/4b0e8dd59a6f738cf27dea81335b8c66.jpg
Thank you

Are you using any baked indirect light? Simulating the light bouncing off one surface to illuminate another can significantly brighten up an indoor space, as well as improve the realism and perceived quality/attractiveness of the scene.

Yes I am using baked indirect light.

This is currently what I have  : https://imgur.com/OZhelSy
The light appears too bright compared to the surrounding that has been lit. I want the surrounding to light up more without increasing the white spot of the light.
The second image is from blender which is what I would like to achieve.

It would also help significantly if you edit to include a reference image for the sort of look you are trying to achieve.  There are many horror movies with night scenes and a variety of cinematic tricks and techniques are used to achieve them. Seeing an example of what you want will help focus answers on relevant solutions.

Thanks for the suggestion I have edited the post to include images

I was able to solve the issue by applying texture to the walls.
Earlier I had the default unity material with no texture. This material created very intense bright spots after baking.
But after adding a wall texture I was able to solve this issue.
I also added a area light from above to equally lit most of the area.


Can you include the texture you used? Was there anything specific about this texture's colour or its alpha channel that made it suitable for this fix?

It was a plaster texture from ambientcg.com. There are plenty of those on that site. I had downloaded two and combined them. I don't think there was anything special in them.
